# Connect Samsung Bluetooth Smart Remote (2016) to RaspberryPi Bluetooth (Zero W)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-smart-tv, bluetooth-gatt, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to connect my Samsung Bluetooth Smart Remote (2016) (no mouse function) to a RaspberryPi Zero W which then should send actions through IR or IP when a button on the remote is pressed.
Sofar I've managed to connect the bluetooth remote to the raspberry pi zero with gatttool:

```
sudo gatttool -I -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX stands for the mac of the remote. Typing `connect` in the interactive mode then connects to the remote, when the remote is in pairing mode (press back and play for 3s).
The connection sofar seems to be established successfully, the mac adress font is now colored blue and also bluetoothctl shows that it is connected to 'Smart Remote 2016' in blue letters.

But from now on, I don't get anything further. The next step I'd expect to establish a connection to the HID service of the remote and getting new devices listed in `/dev/input` and therefore be able to receive commands when buttons are pressed on the remote. If I right now press a button, nothing happens on my raspberry.

In the gatttool (type primary) I discovered, that the device has 10 services, listed as follows:

```
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0007 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Generic Access
attr handle: 0x0010, end grp handle: 0x0013 uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Generic Attribute
attr handle: 0x0030, end grp handle: 0x0040 uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Device Information
attr handle: 0x0050, end grp handle: 0x0052 uuid: 00001803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Link Loss
attr handle: 0x0053, end grp handle: 0x0055 uuid: 00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Immediate Alert
attr handle: 0x0056, end grp handle: 0x0058 uuid: 00001804-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Tx Power
attr handle: 0x0060, end grp handle: 0x0063 uuid: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Battery Service
attr handle: 0x0070, end grp handle: 0x00a7 uuid: 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Human Interface Device
attr handle: 0x5000, end grp handle: 0x5005 uuid: 0d916f56-8570-4d50-a34f-20574da51001, Unknown Service
attr handle: 0xff00, end grp handle: 0xff05 uuid: 9e5d1e47-5c13-43a0-8635-82ad38a1386f, Unknown Service
```

Did anyone ever try this before or does know how to enable the Human Interface Device?
I'd really appreciate any help in this topic! Thanks.

Comment: You may not want to use `gatttool` as that has been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617). Using `bluetoothctl` would be the preferred tool currently. Is the following answer of any help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765300/7721752

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I followed the instruction but when trying to connect, it only connects for a moment and directly disconnects again after one second. When connecting to the device using `bluetoothctl` without pairing (also remove previously paired devices) the services with uuid are found but also the connection is directly lost, after about 5 seconds. Also no new devices in `/dev/input`