# How do I connect a L2CAP-based Bluetooth Camera Shutter (AB Shutter 3) to Linux and get the key event in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, pybluez, l2cap

### Goal

I have a [HITSLAM Camera Shutter Bluetooth button](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L9V5FLL) (which is a AB Shutter 3 device, a common Bluetooth camera remote control) which I want to connect to my NVIDIA Jetson Nano using Bluetooth, so that I can use the button's input for some task.

### What I Have Done

I am using the PyBluez library for connecting. I use the following to find out which port and protocol the AB Shutter 3 uses (where `target_device_address` is the AB Shutter 3's device address):

```
service_matches = bt.find_service(name=None,uuid=None,address=target_device_address)
first_match = service_matches[0]
print("Port {}, Name {}, Host {}, Protocol {}".format(first_match['port'], first_match['name'], first_match['host'], first_match['protocol']))
```

This is how I get the port (17) which to connect to and the protocol (L2CAP) it uses.

Now, I try to connect to it using the following:

```
client_sock = bt.BluetoothSocket(bt.L2CAP)
client_sock.connect((target_device_address,port))
```

I have also used Python's native `socket` library (which have yielded me the same results):

```
client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_SEQPACKET, socket.BTPROTO_L2CAP)
client_sock.connect((target_device_address,port))
```

Which it successfully connects according to `hcitool`, after which I wait for user input:

```
if target_device_address in (subprocess.getoutput("hcitool con")).split():
    print('connected')
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        print(str(data))
```

### Issues

- The device actually does not show up as an input in `/dev/input/`. When I connect it manually through the GUI, it shows up as `/dev/input/event5`.
- After connecting, there is no input captured by my script.

### My Questions

- How does it connect according to `hcitool con` yet not be registered as an input device (and register any inputs)?
- What do you suggest doing? I have looked everywhere and do not seem to get a proper solution. There is a [workaround with implementing a bash script that uses `bluetoothctl`](https://www.hackster.io/AdiK/selfie-hack-control-leds-using-selfie-bluetooth-remote-93558e) to connect to the Bluetooth remote control, but it just does not make sense to me why Python cannot make this connection and retrieve information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be not to use `hcitool` as it was [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) back in 2017.

I prefer to use the BlueZ D-Bus API directly which is documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt

This can be accessed in Python using the [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) library

I am going to assume your Bluetooth adapter is on `hci0` on the Jetson but you can check this with:

```
$ busctl tree org.bluez
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
    └─/org/bluez/hci0
```

This would make the code something like:

```py
import pydbus

DEVICE_ADDR = '11:22:22:E7:CE:BE'

# DBus object paths
BLUEZ_SERVICE = 'org.bluez'
ADAPTER_PATH = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_path = f"{ADAPTER_PATH}/dev_{DEVICE_ADDR.upper().replace(':', '_')}"

# setup dbus
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, '/')
adapter = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, ADAPTER_PATH) 
device = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, device_path)

device.Connect()
```

This should create the event at `/dev/input/` and I would use the python library [evdev](https://pypi.org/project/evdev/) to get the inputs as was done in the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765300/7721752

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed - it makes sense because I am trying to actually connect to a device, not create a socket for exchange of data. One interesting thing to note is that when I tried to connect to the device using the device address I had previously, it actually changed. So moving forward, I would use `PyBluez` to search for the shutter and get the device address, then use `pydbus` to connect to it.